# Cardinality of product of two sets is the product of the cardinalities of both sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $|X| = n$ and $|Y| = m$. We want to show $|X \times Y | = mn$.

MY attempt: By hypothesis, we can find bijections $f: X \to \{ 1,...,n\}$ and $g : Y \to \{1,...,m\}$. We want to find a bijection from $X \times Y \to \{ 1,....,nm\}$. I was thinking maybe of $h(x) = 2^x    3^y$. But it doesnt seem to be bijective. How can we find a bijection? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is trivial to see that if $m=1$ then it holds, as we can map $x\in X$ to $(x,\ast)\in X\times Y$ where $Y=\{\ast\}$ and this is a bijection.

Suppose this is true for $m=k$, we wish to show it is also true for $m=k+1$. Let $g\colon X\times Y_k\rightarrow \{1,\ldots kn\}$ be a bijection. We also let $h\colon X\rightarrow \{1,\ldots, n\}$ be a bijection.

We wish to find a bijection $f\colon X\times Y_{k+1}\rightarrow\{1,\ldots,(k+1)n\}$ where $Y_{k+1}=Y_k\sqcup\{\ast \}$.

We can define the bijection $f$ by setting
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
g(x,y) & \text{if }y\neq \ast,\\
kn+h(x) & \text{if }y=\ast.
\end{cases}$$
and it is readily seen that this is indeed a bijection. This completes the induction.

Answer (score 1):

You could map $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ to $(g(y)-1)n+f(x)$. This is a bijection. The idea is that first you "list" all pairs whose $y$ coordinate satisfies $g(y)=1$, and there are $n$ such pairs, then all pairs whose $y$ coordinate satisfies $g(y)=2$, and again there are $n$ pairs, etc.

Comment: Im having hard time trying to you the function you defined is bijective. Can you help me? thanks